# ¿De qué manera puedo sumar las opciones de precios de un "ComboBox" y colocarlas un "jTextField" en JAVA?

Tags: java

Hay varios `ComboBox` y en la parte del código quiero asignarle a cada opción de cada `ComboBox` un precio y poder sumarlos para al final mostrarlos en un `jTextField`. ¿Cómo puedo hacer dicho procedimiento?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código que tienes hasta ahora?

Comment: Podrias dejar el codigo que estas utilizando hasta ahora, lo que haz intentado y en que falla!

Comment: puedes sumarlas de extrayendo el elemento del combobox y comvirtiendolo a double, Double resultado = Double.parseDouble(combobox1.getSelectedItem()+"") + Double.parseDouble(combobox2.getSelectedItem()+"") + Double.parseDouble(combobox3.getSelectedItem()+"");